# How to make facebook post id not shown after publishing a wall post

Tags: facebook, post

I just wrote an HTTP Post to write on the user's wall. My http post code is below:

```
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_id.'/feed';
    $fields = array(
        'message'=>urlencode($message),
        'access_token'=>urlencode($access_token)
    );
    $fields_string ='';
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { 
        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
    }
    rtrim($fields_string,'&');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    $post_id = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

It works great, but the only problem is that the post id gets echoed back to the page when the post is done. Is there a way to make it so that the post id won't be shown on the webpage? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try add `@` symbol before `curl_exec`:

```
$post_id = @curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Ok I got it. Need to put this line:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);